# req.body is returning a default value and not my POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm sure I am making a small error and I cannot find the answer in other questions. Basically every time I try to make a POST request the console is displaying "{}" instead of the value from the post request. I am using EJS and Node.js to deal with this POST request.

Here's the code from the ejs file

```
<label> My Favourite Saying</label>
    <form action ="/users/dashboard" method ="POST">
        <div class = "form-group">
        <input 
        type="name" 
        id="favSaying" 
        class="form-control"
        placeholder = "Enter phrase here"
        />
        </div>
        <small id="FavSayingInst" class="form-text text-muted">
            Enter a phrase to have it stored for the next time you login.
        </small>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark mt-2">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the code from the handler file

```
//Handle the fav saying
router.post('/dashboard', (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log("test123");
  //User.findOneAndUpdate({email:'tester2@gmail.com', favSaying})
  req.flash('store_msg', 'Your phrase has been stored!');
  res.redirect('/views/dashboard');
});
```

I've already added the body parser so I know it's not that, :

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

//EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine','ejs');

//DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').MongoURI;

//Connect to Mongo
mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected...'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

//Bodyparser
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 's',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

//Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Connect flash
app.use(flash());

//Vars
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.store_msg = req.flash('store_msg');
    next();
});

//Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index2')); //The first comment is where the webpage routes to, the second is the js file
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; 

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on Port  ${PORT}`));
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting "{}" instead of my values? I have

Comment: is your path is correct? `"/users/dashboard"`

Comment: @Kaasim Shaikh Can you post your `server.js` code??

Comment: @ManjeetThakur I think so, when I click the button the console in visual studio prints out "test123"

Comment: @KaasimShaikh what do you want `response`?

Comment: for `req.body` you are getting empty object?

Comment: @seunggabi if I type anything in the "input" field I want that POST method to be detected. Eventually I want to send it to my MongooseDB

Comment: @AZ_ console.log(req.body);   returns "{}"

Comment: use middleware with `body-parser` also .

Comment: @Kaasim Shaikh Which version of `express` r u using??

Comment: @Subburaj  Version : express 4.17.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input element should have a name attribute to transmit the data into the request.

Comment: That means I need to go to bed....hahaha thank you very much. This fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should have 'name' attribute in your input tags.

Answer (score -2):

You need to check your `response`.

```
// POST method route
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.body);
});
```

Try it.

You have to fix this.

```
<input type="text" name="name" ...>
```

That's why, `<input>` tag type don't have `name`. 
And name is `post body` field key.

Comment: This will return the same thing as console.log which is "{}"

Comment: @KaasimShaikh okay I undertand. wait for me

Comment: @KaasimShaikh fix this.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo on my end. Still no go.

Comment: @KaasimShaikh ..... <input type="text" name="name" ...> I already this. name attribute..;;